# help about supremum norm proof

Tags: normed-spaces

T:( $C'[0,1] ,||x||₁)\to (C[0,1]$,||x||∞)

Tx(t)=x'(t) for any x is in  C'[0,1]

$||x||₁=||x||_{\infty}+||x′||$∞   how can we prove that equality?

$||x||_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}|$

$||x||_{\infty}=\sup|x_n|$

Comment: is $x$ a sequence of functions in $C[0,1]$?

Comment: yes,x a sequence of functions in C'[0,1]